# How to Retrieve data from firebase to web without using this get button?

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So in this code that I need to put the ID to get the rest of the data from the table. But I need to get those data row by row without using any button. I mean I want to show all data in all tables without using the get button.

like this according to my firebase database

[image: firebase database]

1. name = sadsad, password = qwer, phone = 213213, username = 544
2. name = lakshan, password = qwe, phone = 0715690431, username = 78788787
3. name = Pakaya, password = 258, phone = 08454554, username = 258963258963

**Html and JS code**

```js
function getdata() {
    var user=document.getElementById("Admins").value;
    //firebase data retrieval function
    //path of your data
    //.once will get all your data in one time
    firebase.database().ref('Admins/'+user).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        //here we will get data
        //enter your field name
        var name=snapshot.val().name;
        var phone=snapshot.val().phone;
        var password=snapshot.val().password;

        //now we have data in variables
        //now show them in our html

        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=name;
        document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML=phone;
        document.getElementById("password").innerHTML=password;
    })
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Retrieve data</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h2>Enter name of user to get information</h2>
    <input type="text" id="Admins" required="required"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="getdata();">Get</button>
</center>
<center>
    <p>Name: <strong id="name"></strong></p>
    <p>Phone Number: <strong id="phone"></strong></p>
    <p>Password: <strong id="password"></strong></p>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're not sure how to call `getdata()` without physically clicking your button.

In your `<script>` tags, or in your `script.js` file, simply add `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getdata)`.

This will call `getdata` once the document contents are loaded.

Note that this still might be too early to get the data, if, for instance, you need to wait for a user to be signed in, in which case I suggest looking up the documentation of the `authStateChanged` listener.  (That's the only part of this answer specific to Firebase -- otherwise it's just a JS / HTML question.)

Finally, as a general note, it's considered best practice not to put your JS inline with your HTML, but instead in an event listener, as described above.

Comment: as I mentioned above, in your script tags, if you have your JavaScript and HTML all-in-one file, or, in your script file if you keep them separately